How will apache server + mod_wsgi will recognize changes made to vitualhost or newly added virtualhost without restarting or reloading?
`I am using Apache Server with mod_wsgi for hosting my python django applications.
Versions:
Python 3.9.18
Server version: Apache/2.4.57
mod-wsgi==4.7.1
One of my application virtual host configuration with two different versions:
#Students Webservice Config
 Listen 9002
 <VirtualHost *:9002>
        ServerName test.myapp.com
        ErrorLog /var/log/webservice_error.log

        WSGIPassAuthorization On
        WSGIDaemonProcess Tes9002 python-path=/home/uoadmin/releases/1.0.0/students:/home/admin/releases/1.0.0/shared display-name=%{GROUP}
        WSGIProcessGroup Tes9002

        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/admin/releases/1.0.0/students/conf/wsgi.py
        <Directory /home/admin/releases/1.0.0/students/conf>
            <Files wsgi.py>
             Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:9002>
        ServerName dev.myapp.com
        ErrorLog /var/log/webservice_error.log

        WSGIPassAuthorization On
        WSGIDaemonProcess Dev9002 python-      path=/home/uoadmin/releases/1.1.0/students:/home/admin/releases/1.1.0/shared display-name=%{GROUP}
        WSGIProcessGroup Dev9002

        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/admin/releases/1.1.0/students/conf/wsgi.py
        <Directory /home/admin/releases/1.1.0/students/conf>
            <Files wsgi.py>
             Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

So, When the source code is modified
I can referesh the wsgi daemon using
touch /home/uoadmin/releases/1.1.0/students/conf/wsgi.py
touch /home/uoadmin/releases/1.0.0/students/conf/wsgi.py
But when I added new virtualhost to the above configuration file or else when I modify above file the apache server unable to recognize modifications made the existing virtualhost or newly added virtualhost until doing
apachectl graceful (or)
apachectl restart (or)
systemctl reload httpd
but all the commands above killing the ongoing requests forcefully directly terminating them.
How to handle above situation.
I want to know how will apache server recognize modifications to virtualhost or newly added virtual host without reloading or restarting.
If above is not possible then is there anyway for restarting or reloading  apache server gracefully that is without terminating or killing other ongoing requests or daemons while using apache server + mod_wsgi for serving python with django?
reload and restart gracefully are not working for mod_wsgi that is they are forcefully killing other processing daemons`

There is no way around a graceful reload of the apache http server. That however should never terminate the processing of current requests. That is the whole point of the "graceful" reload.

But while using mod_wsgi daemon, 'graceful' is not working, forcefully terminating other ongoing requests.

The documentation of mod_wsgi mentions a graceful-timeout too ... Did you specify it? https://www.modwsgi.org/en/latest/release-notes/version-4.1.0.html

But overall it appears that this is a limitation of the apache http server if you us processes not being subprocesses of the http daemon itself. The apache server gives those processes 3 seconds to finish, apparently, that's all you have.

No i didn't try
graceful-timeout
But I got to know that there is no other way that while using mod_wsgi daemon
graceful restart will not work as it is not a managed as child process of apache server instead it will be managed as managed process.
So, graceful restart is only for apache's own worker child processes.

That is correct. If you use wsgi as a daemon this seems to be the case.
